# Test component with template - dynamic disable function

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have popular situation:
Template have disabled element depend on another input element.

```
<input id="email" type="text" [(ngModel)]="login.username" name="username"
<button type="button" id="login-button" [disabled]="(login.username.length < 5)"</button>
```

In my test I check situation before I insert email data, and after this insert:

```
expect(loginButton.disabled).toBe(true); // PASS
expect(email.value === null).toBe(false); // PASS
console.log(email.value); // RETURN: null

email.value = "admin";
email.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
fixture.detectChanges();

console.log(email.value); // RETURN: "admin"    
expect(email.value === null).toBe(false); // PASS
expect(loginButton.disabled).not.toBe(true); // FAILD
```

Why `loginButton.disabled` is still disabled? If I make the same in Chrome console it activate login button after `email.dispatchEvent` is send:

```
var email = document.getElementById("email");
email.value = "admin";
email.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer. Since Angular2 RC5 release all ngModel operation are async, so during a test I should use async and whenStable() method, like hire:

```
it('Test template fields', async(()=>{
    expect(loginButton.disabled).toBe(true); // PASS
    expect(email.value === null).toBe(false); // PASS
    console.log(email.value); // RETURN: null

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {

        email.value = "admin";
        email.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        fixture.detectChanges();

        console.log(email.value); // RETURN: "admin"    
        expect(email.value === null).toBe(false); // PASS
        expect(loginButton.disabled).not.toBe(true); // FAILD

    });
});
```